# Как сделать редирект с сайта для некоторых ip адресов

Tags: редирект

Есть список ip. Как сделать, чтобы если, пользователь зашёл с ip адреса, который есть в списке, перенаправляло на другой сайт?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение на PHP:

```
    <?

    function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
    {
        if (headers_sent() === false)
        {
            header('Location: ' . $url, true, ($permanent === true) ? 301 : 302);
        }

        exit();
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '89.179.244.127')
        Redirect('http://www.google.com/', false);

    ?>
```

Надеюсь, идея понятна: мы получаем из server variables IP клиента, если он такой то - делаем редирект.

Comment: Мне PHP не очень подходит, можно ли реализовать это на JavaScript?

Comment: К сожалению, без участия сервера Вы не можете на клиентской стороне получить server variables, среди котрых содержится клиентский IP. Какое то участие сервера - необходимо. Хоть одна строчка, выполняющаяся на сервере :-) Другое дело - можно это сделать на на php, а на JS, котрый выполняется на nodeJS.

Comment: Какжется, я нагуглил решение со внешним поставщиком данных: https://ipdata.co/blog/how-to-get-the-ip-address-in-javascript/ .Там идея такая: мы спрашиваем у некого сервера наш IP, пользуясь его API

Comment: спасибо, помогло) Использовал CloudFlare